# How to get an output/log from model.fit() while it's busy training

Tags: tensorflow.js

I am new to Tensorflow.js.

Coming from Keres, I am used to getting a default log like this printed during training:

```
Epoch 1/2
320/320 [==============================] - 7s 21ms/step - loss: 5.6595
Epoch 2/2
320/320 [==============================] - 5s 15ms/step - loss: 5.5646
```

However, when I run `await model.fit()` in Tensorflow.js, my console just hangs with no output. Is there a setting I can pass to `model.fit()` so that I can output some sort of rudimentary log to the console during training?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a callback to [`.fit()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.5/#tf.Sequential.fit) which gets callled on different events (`onTrainBegin`, `onTrainEnd`, `onEpochBegin`, `onEpochEnd`, `onBatchBegin`, `onBatchEnd`)

Example:

```
model.fit(xs, ys, {
  callbacks: {
    onTrainBegin: async () => {
      console.log("onTrainBegin")
    },
    onTrainEnd: async (epoch, logs) => {
      console.log("onTrainEnd" + epoch + JSON.stringify(logs))
    },
    onEpochBegin: async (epoch, logs) => {
      console.log("onEpochBegin" + epoch + JSON.stringify(logs))
    },
    onEpochEnd: async (epoch, logs) => {
      console.log("onEpochEnd" + epoch + JSON.stringify(logs))
    },
    onBatchBegin: async (epoch, logs) => {
      console.log("onBatchBegin" + epoch + JSON.stringify(logs))
    },
    onBatchEnd: async (epoch, logs) => {
      console.log("onBatchEnd" + epoch + JSON.stringify(logs))
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I added a sample code to your answer for future visitors to copy/paste